# Is there a concept of demonic possession in Hinduism?

Tags: belief

In Hinduism, is there a concept of demonic spirits being able to take over the thoughts and actions of a person? If so, what are these demons and what scriptures mention them?

I know that the Bhagavad Gita mentions a person having demoniac qualities but I don't think this is the same as being possessed by a demon, unless someone can correct me on this.

Comment: I think there is a story Kali (short a) possessing King Parikshit and he did many wrong things for which he was cursed by a sage to die after being bitten by snake in 7 days....

Comment: @iammilind that question has no answer on it, nor is it about demonic possession

Comment: The intention of duplicate is that the future answer should go in that post to have better inter connection. It seems that the question about exorcism which is related to demons. The word used there is more general as "spirits".